What is the recommended way to convert a PriorityQueue to an array in C#?
I'm really having a hard time with Microsoft's implementation of PriorityQueue because it's missing most of the extension methods that you'll find in other collections.  There is no ToArray method, nor is there AsEnumerable. I haven't been able to find any built-in way to convert a PriorityQueue to an array.
In Java, this can be accomplished with a built-in ToArray method, but for some reason C# lacks this. Does anyone know why?  It's bad enough that you have to specify both value and priority even when they're the same, but to not even include an intuitive way to convert the collection to an array is just plain annoying IMO.
Does anybody know if there's a way to do this without manually iterating over the PriorityQueue?  I could convert to an array by means of IEnumerable, but as I said, PriorityQueue in C# doesn't implement AsEnumerable. I realize I could do a foreach over the PriorityQueue and build the array manually but I just wanted to make sure there isn't a more concise option available.

The class is supposed to be used for processing one item at at time, in order of priority. You do this typically while items are being added by one or more item sources. What is the point of getting all items in an array when a new item could get added just after you got your array?

Are you interest in enumerating the elements in the priority queue in any order (irrespective of their priority), or in the same order that the elements are dequeued according to their priority?

Are you interested solely for the case that the value and priority are the same, or for the more general case where the TElement and the TPriority are distinct?


I realize I could do a foreach over the PriorityQueue and build the array manually

Could you? It doesn’t implement IEnumerable<T>. The reason for this is that it’s backed by a heap, so you can’t iterate over it in priority order without actually removing elements.
You can iterate over it in an arbitrary (in practice, heap) order with its collection of UnorderedItems, collect that to an array, and sort the result. For example, if priorities are the same as their corresponding elements, like in the case you brought up:
var items = priorityQueue.UnorderedItems.Select(ep => ep.Item1).ToArray();
Array.Sort(items);

(This sort will be faster than heapsort.)
The only option more efficient than this would be to take the backing array directly from the priority queue without copying it, but the other .NET collections don’t support that either, and you apparently don’t want (priority, element) tuples anyway.
For the general case where priorities aren’t the same as elements, here’s an implementation of a method to drain the queue specifically into an array (basically the manual foreach you were getting at):
static TValue[] Drain<TElement, TPriority>(
    this PriorityQueue<TElement, TPriority> queue,
) {
    var result = new TValue[queue.UnorderedItems.Count];
    int i = 0;

    while (queue.TryDequeue(out var element, out _)) {
        result[i++] = element;
    }

    return result;
}

(Note that a List<T> is cleaner.)
Otherwise, non-destructively, you have the usual options to sort a collection of (priority, element) tuples, e.g.
var items = priorityQueue.UnorderedItems
    .OrderBy(ep => ep.Item2)
    .Select(ep => ep.Item1)
    .ToArray();


One more point. The Array.Sort(items); looks ineffective. I guess you would want to sort the elements according to their priority, but their associated priority has already been discarded with the projection kv => kv.Item1.

@TheodorZoulias: The OP mentioned implied that in their case, priorities = values.

You mean this phrase from the question: "It's bad enough that you have to specify both value and priority even when they're the same." I am not sure that the OP wants to impose this constraint to their question. I would say that a general solution, where the TElement and the TPriority are distinct, might be more useful overall for the C# community. Of course we could wait until the OP clarifies what they want.

To clarify, when I mentioned foreach, I meant I could implement my own custom IEnumerable method and do the foreach over that.

@TheodorZoulias What I'm referring to is the fact that C# doesn't give us the option to just do PriorityQueue<int> instead of PriorityQueue<int, int> even in cases where the value and the priority are the same.  For example, if I'm enqueuing a list of integers to have them queued in sorted order, I would have to do pq.Enqueue(val, val) instead of just pq.Enqueue(val).  PriorityQueue could just assume that value and priority will always be the same.  Having to do val, val every time just looks ugly to me from as aesthetic perspective.
